# How to write mappings for a stored procedure

Tags: c#, nhibernate, stored-procedures, mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

There is an excellent post on how to map return values for a stored procedure call here:
http://elegantcode.com/2008/11/23/populating-entities-from-stored-procedures-with-nhibernate/

The mapping in this example has been done through hbm files.

I am trying to use the latest version of Nhibernate (3.2) where we can do mapping through code. I really want to find out the C# code that would create a mapping like below:

```
<sql-query name="GetProductsByCategoryId">
    <return class="Product">
      <return-property column="ProductID" name="Id" />
      <return-property column="ProductName" name="Name" />
      <return-property column="SupplierID" name="Supplier" />
      <return-property column="CategoryID" name="Category" />
      <return-property column="QuantityPerUnit" name="QuantityPerUnit" />
      <return-property column="UnitPrice" name="UnitPrice" />
      <return-property column="UnitsInStock" name="UnitsInStock" />
      <return-property column="UnitsOnOrder" name="UnitsOnOrder" />
      <return-property column="ReorderLevel" name="ReorderLevel" />
      <return-property column="Discontinued" name="Discontinued" />
    </return>
    exec dbo.GetProductsByCategoryId :CategoryId
</sql-query>
```

Comment: It's visible now ;) (you can remove the comment)

Comment: @VishalKumar Could you post an example where you only use code for invoking stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I never tried it, by you should take a look to the extension method `AddNamedQuery(..)`: you call it from you `Configuration` instance  (`NHibernate.Cfg` namespace)).

[Some examples](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.Test/CfgTest/Loquacious/NamedQueryTests.cs) on the NHibernate test project.

By the way, you can mix the new 3.2 mapping-by-code and xml one.
Start to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914655/how-to-map-a-sql-function-as-named-query-with-nhibernates-loquacious-mapping);

Comment: Thanks Michele, I know about the mixing up part. In fact I used the classic hbm file mapping just like above to make it work through 3.2. But the AddNamedQuery(..) is really what I am looking for to do mapping by code.